# Executar Javascript na URL(plugins..)

Tags: javascript, url

Como faço para executar trechos de JavaScript na barra de endereçamento, tentei no Firefox algo como:  `javascript: alert("lol")`, mas parece ser uma técnica antiga e que não funciona(ao menos não no Firefox).

A ideia é ter um favorito na barra de favoritos no qual é um trecho de JavaScript, para que eu clique nele e ele faça alguns procedimentos na página atual(no qual o utilizador está presente), como por exemplo, exibir o endereço da página, capturar um valor de elemento na DOM..

É possível? Existem plugins especiais para isso(firefox, chrome..), e ainda, seria possivel usar JQuery para facilitar na codificação?

Comment: Se você quer criar um script que funcione como um plugin para paginas de terceiros, entao aconselho que use o Greasemonkey para o Firefox ou o Tampermonkey para o Chrome/Opera

Comment: tem tantas formas de fazer algo parecido com isso. Digite "execute javascript url firefox" no google e veja as opções. Essa pergunta não teve um esforço mínimo de pesquisa.

Comment: Talvez por existir tantas formas, em tantas linguagens(br,en,es..), por que não um tópico na maior comunidade de programação no Brasil, com respostas completas e úteis com informações claras e atuais? EU penso assim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O nome desse recurso é [*bookmarklet*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) e não depende de *plugins* para funcionar. Segundo a Wikipedia:

> Um **bookmarklet** é um pequeno programa em JavaScript que é armazenado como uma URL nos Favoritos.

Os *bookmarklets* são favoritos que utilizam o protocolo `javascript:` ao invés de `http://` ou `https://`

O método mais difundido para criar *bookmarklets* é criar um link com a tag `<a>` que pode ser "instalado" ao clicar e arrastar o link para a barra de favoritos.

```html
<a href="javascript:alert('Olá mundo');">Olá mundo</a>
```

É possível utilizar jQuery no *bookmarklet*, mas é necessário incluir a biblioteca manualmente (código adaptado de [*Bookmarklet Creator with Script Includer*](http://mrcoles.com/bookmarklet/)):

```
javascript:(function(){
  // cria script
  var s = document.createElement("script");
  s.src = 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js';
  // adiciona para executar depois que carregar
  s.addEventListener('load', function() {
    (function($){
      var jQuery = $;
      // seu código entra aqui
      // jQuer já estará carregado
    })(jQuery.noConflict(true))
  }, false);
  // adiciona script na página
  document.body.appendChild(s);
})()
```

Nessa implementação falta apenas verificar se o jQuery já está carregado na página.

Comment: Escolhi sua resposta por ser mais direta, e completa, gostei dos detalhes do protocolo e do jquery, realmente é bom saber disso. Grato

Answer (score 4):

Você pode salvar como favorito como deseja.

> Estou com a versão 42.0 do firefox e no mesmo funciona da seguinte forma:

Adicione a página como favorito.

> Ctrl + D e concluir.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após isso, vá a pagina que adicionou, clique com o botão direito em cima e clique em propriedades.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Feito isso, cole seu javascript no lugar da url e clique em salvar. Seu javascript deve seguir essa "sintaxe":

> javascript:alert('Lol');

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Feito isso, basta clicar no favorito que ele irá executar o script.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Outra forma é ir direto em seu navegador, apagar o link que possui, digitar o `script` e apertar enter.

Por último, você pode fazer via console do browser (Ctrl + Shift + J) e digitar o script que deseja.

> Essas formas foram testadas no Firefox 42, Google Chrome 42 e o Internet Explorer 11.

Answer (score 0):

Acrescento à excelente resposta escolhida, a do [Sanção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/13561/san%C3%A7%C3%A3o), uma solução de se colocar a execução de um bookMarkLet na barra de extensões da família ChroMe (ChroMe, Canary, ChroMium):

[Bare minimum Chrome extension to inject a JS file into the given page when you click on the browser action icon. The script then inserts a new div into the DOM.](https://gist.github.com/danharper/8364399)

**NOTA:** Apor o script/bookMarkLet desejado no arquivo [inject.js], logo após o trecho de código:

> document.body.appendChild(div);

Para poder inserir a extensão citada acima no ChroMe, proceda da seguinte forma:

- Abra o endereço de extensões do ChroMe: (chrome://extensions/)
- Habilite o [Modo do desenvolvedor], localizado na parte superior direita da tela
- Clique em "Carregar sem compactação"
- Selecione a pasta da extensão que você baixou acima (a pasta que contenha o arquivo manifest.json)
- Confirme, e pronto!
- Basta clicar no ícone da nova extensão e então será executado o script ou a chamada ao bookMarkLet desejado
- Se você quiser um atalho para esta nova extensão abra a opção do menu [Extensões --> Atalhos de teclado --> Nova extensão] e acrescente o atalho

REFERÊNCIA: <kbd>Stack OverFlow:</kbd> [How to modify an extension from the Chrome Web Store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680682/how-to-modify-an-extension-from-the-chrome-web-store)